# SupportedPlatform in Blazor template's csproj

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

The blazor "standalone" template includes this in the project's `.csproj`:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <SupportedPlatform Include="browser" />
</ItemGroup>
```

What is it? Is it documented somewhere?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the explanation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/class-libraries?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#browser-compatibility-analyzer-for-blazor-webassembly):

> Blazor WebAssembly apps target the full .NET API surface area, but not all .NET APIs are supported on WebAssembly due to browser sandbox constraints. Unsupported APIs throw PlatformNotSupportedException when running on WebAssembly. ... For Blazor WebAssembly apps, this means checking that APIs are supported in browsers

So it informs the analysers and compiler to check that the app only uses BCL/FCL classes that are wasm-compatible.